# why are my textures randomizing whenever i reopen a file

Tags: texturing

i imported some objects from roblox studios and then closed the file and reopened it and it looked like this
[image]

(this isnt the original file i deleted that one this was a reattempt) it dosent happen every time i reopen it but once it does it does not change even if i re import the file it stays like that even on other projects i tried remaking  the file and after a while the same thing happened. i tried uv unwrapping it from a quick tutorial but that just made it worse and cover the entire model in those textures. i dont know what to do and im really new to blender

[image]

edit: the left is what the sword looks like before it gets messed up